# Mongoose push value in array inside array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My model:

```
Restaurant = mongoose.Schema(
  name: String
  menuItems: [
    name: String
    dishes: [
      name: String
    ]
  ] 
)
```

I'll need to push item to 'dishes' array:

```
Restaurant.update {id: restID, 'menuItems.id': menuItemID}
                  $addToSet: {'menuItems.$.dishes': newDish}
                  (err, res) ->
                     ...
```

But nothing happens. What I'm doing wrong? Thanks for any advise.

Comment: did u figured it out? trying to do the same here

Answer (score 1):

The virtual `id` field can't be used when updating; you have to use the actual `_id` name instead:

```
Restaurant.update {_id: restID, 'menuItems._id': menuItemID},
                  $addToSet: {'menuItems.$.dishes': newDish}
                  (err, res) ->
                     ...
```